# Order by on two columns very slow compared to order by on a single column

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I am using Postgres and I see that with order by on two columns, my query is several order of magnitude slower compared to the order by on only one column. I have approximately 29.5 million rows in the table under consideration.

Here are result of three different queries:

With order by only on id:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "api_meterdata"."id", "api_meterdata"."meter_id", "api_meterdata"."datetime", "api_meter"."id" FROM "api_meterdata" INNER JOIN "api_meter" ON ( "api_meterdata"."meter_id" = "api_meter"."id" ) ORDER BY "api_meterdata"."id" DESC LIMIT 100;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                            

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 Limit  (cost=0.44..321.49 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=0.407..30.424 rows=100 loops=1)    
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.44..94824299.30 rows=29535145 width=20) (actual time=0.402..30.090 rows=100 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8147
         ->  Index Scan Backward using api_meterdata_pkey on api_meterdata  (cost=0.44..58053041.74 rows=29535145 width=16) (actual time=0.103..0.867 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.144 rows=82 loops=100)
               ->  Seq Scan on api_meter  (cost=0.00..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.153 rows=83 loops=1)  Planning time:
0.491 ms  Execution time: 30.701 ms (9 rows)
```

With order by only on datetime:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "api_meterdata"."id", "api_meterdata"."meter_id", "api_meterdata"."datetime", "api_meter"."id" FROM "api_meterdata" INNER JOIN "api_meter" ON ( "api_meterdata"."meter_id" = "api_meter"."id" ) ORDER BY "api_meterdata"."datetime" ASC LIMIT 100;
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.44..321.50 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=1.245..37.054 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.44..94825493.68 rows=29535313 width=20) (actual time=1.238..36.652 rows=100 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8148
         ->  Index Scan using api_meterdata_datetime_index on api_meterdata  (cost=0.44..58054026.95 rows=29535313 width=16) (actual time=0.851..1.501 rows=100 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.172 rows=82 loops=100)
               ->  Seq Scan on api_meter  (cost=0.00..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.192 rows=83 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.483 ms
 Execution time: 37.340 ms
(9 rows)
```

With order by on both datetime and id:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "api_meterdata"."id", "api_meterdata"."meter_id", "api_meterdata"."datetime", "api_meter"."id" FROM "api_meterdata" INNER JOIN "api_meter" ON ( "api_meterdata"."meter_id" = "api_meter"."id" ) ORDER BY "api_meterdata"."datetime" ASC, "api_meterdata"."id" DESC LIMIT 100;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=3064122.28..3064122.53 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=146772.167..146772.372 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=3064122.28..3137955.90 rows=29533446 width=20) (actual time=146772.164..146772.242 rows=100 loops=1)
         Sort Key: api_meterdata.datetime, api_meterdata.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.87..1935375.21 rows=29533446 width=20) (actual time=0.394..113349.364 rows=29535544 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id)
               ->  Seq Scan on api_meterdata  (cost=0.00..1529287.46 rows=29533446 width=16) (actual time=0.220..47537.991 rows=29535544 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=1.83..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.160..0.160 rows=83 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on api_meter  (cost=0.00..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.071 rows=83 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.290 ms
 Execution time: 146772.500 ms
(12 rows)
```

And here are the indexes on the table:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'api_meterdata';
 schemaname |   tablename   |                  indexname                   | tablespace |                                                      indexdef                                       

------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------
 public     | api_meterdata | api_meterdata_meter_id_36fe63013b50049f_uniq |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX api_meterdata_meter_id_36fe63013b50049f_uniq ON api_meterdata USING btree (meter
_id, datetime)
 public     | api_meterdata | api_meterdata_pkey                           |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX api_meterdata_pkey ON api_meterdata USING btree (id)
 public     | api_meterdata | api_meterdata_f7a5de1d                       |            | CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_f7a5de1d ON api_meterdata USING btree (meter_id)
 public     | api_meterdata | api_meterdata_datetime_index                 |            | CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_datetime_index ON api_meterdata USING btree (datetime)
(4 rows)
```

I can see it is the sorting step which is taking the longest. But not sure why.

Comment: Did you try adding an index on `(datetime, id DESC)`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: There is already an index with (id, datetime). Does the sequence matter? I have tried changing the sort order from datetime ASC, id DES to id DES, datetime ASC too but the query time remains the same.

Comment: Yes, the order matters. An index on `(id, datetime)` is not useful for your 3rd query - and that's why it isn't used. Even the common index on `(datetime, id)` won't be best. It would be good for `ORDER BY datetime, id ;` and `ORDER BY datetime DESC, id DESC;`. The index I suggested will be good for your query, `ORDER BY datetime, id DESC;`, and for `ORDER BY datetime DESC, id ;`. Otherwise the order that the rows are found on the index is half-good, needs additional ordering to fit the wanted sort.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Adding index as suggested does make the query order of magnitude faster as the other queries. I am a bit intrigued that if ordering direction matters then for multiple columns and their combinations already make up a lot of indexes and if one adds up the directions as well for sorting, then that makes it many times more for all possible directions for each of the column combinations. Does it not imply that for a generic control panel when there are multiple columns listed and option of sorting provided along with directions, one would need to add so many indexes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason of the difference in timings is due to several facts:

1. Your queries don't have a `WHERE` clause that filter out which results to retrieve.
2. The speed of the query is defined by the fact that you *DO HAVE* a `LIMIT` clause.
3. If the planner can find an index by which it can retrieve the rows of your query *in the same order* that your `ORDER BY` specifies, it will start picking them one by one, until it has read 100 (the number specified by your `LIMIT` clause. The index, if it is multi-column, will need to have the same columns, in the same order, and with the same ASC, DESC sort directions (or *all of them* reversed).
4. If the planner cannot have an index fulfilling this role, it will have to perform a *SORT* step, put all rows in order in a (temporary, virtual) table, and then retrieve the first 100 rows.

The need for *retrieving all the data* (not just 100 rows already ordered), having to *join* all of them and then having a *Sort* step is what's causing such a big difference in performance. This can be seen crystal clear by using [explain.depesz.com](https://explain.depesz.com/s/HXcJ).

---

Find a simulation of your scenario at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=11821e506f2f20b05db4bf04690076c1)*, with the different cases covered and explained, and the suggestion from @ypercube taken into account for another index. Also note that some of your indexes were redundant.

DDL for your scenario, and some simulated data:

```
CREATE TABLE api_meter
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
) ;
INSERT INTO 
    api_meter
    (id)
SELECT
    generate_series(1, 83) ;
```

... and for the table holding your meter_data

```
CREATE TABLE api_meterdata
(
    id serial /* integer */ PRIMARY KEY,
    meter_id integer REFERENCES api_meter(id),
    datetime timestamp NOT NULL default now()
) ;

-- The PK will have made an implicit index ON (id)

-- Index on (meter_id, datetime); which is probably the *NATURAL KEY*
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX api_meterdata_meter_id_datetime_unique 
    ON api_meterdata (meter_id, datetime) ;

-- The following index is redundant, the column meter_id is already the first in
-- the previous one.
-- CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_meter_id_idx 
--    ON api_meterdata (meter_id) ;

CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_datetime_idx 
    ON api_meterdata (datetime) ;
```

... some simulated data (648001 rows, to make it realistic). The data is less than what you have, but DBFiddle reaches its limits if I try to put more

```
INSERT INTO 
    api_meterdata
    (meter_id, datetime)
SELECT
    random()*82+1, d
FROM
    generate_series(timestamp '2017-01-01', timestamp '2017-01-31', 
                    interval '4 second') AS s(d);

-- Make sure statistics are good
ANALYZE api_meterdata;
ANALYZE api_meter;
```

**Analysis of your 1st query**

```
-- This query doesn't have a WHERE clause, so, indexes will be used based on 
-- ORDER BY + LIMIT (and, eventually, column coverage)
--
-- * The index helping this case is the one corresponding to the PK of 
--   api_meter_data, used in DESC order
-- * A second index will help: the one used for the JOIN condition
-- * How does postgresql choose to JOIN will depend on specific data values 
--   distribution, sizes, etc.
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT 
    api_meterdata.id, api_meterdata.meter_id, api_meterdata.datetime, 
    api_meter.id 
FROM 
    api_meterdata 
    INNER JOIN api_meter ON ( api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id ) 
ORDER BY 
    api_meterdata.id DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                        |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=0.57..20.71 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=0.033..0.188 rows=100 loops=1)                                                                           |
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..130514.61 rows=648001 width=20) (actual time=0.031..0.175 rows=100 loops=1)                                                        |
|         ->  Index Scan Backward using api_meterdata_pkey on api_meterdata  (cost=0.42..20342.44 rows=648001 width=16) (actual time=0.023..0.038 rows=100 loops=1) |
|         ->  Index Only Scan using api_meter_pkey on api_meter  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=100)                       |
|               Index Cond: (id = api_meterdata.meter_id)                                                                                                           |
|               Heap Fetches: 100                                                                                                                                   |
| Planning time: 0.331 ms                                                                                                                                           |
| Execution time: 0.216 ms                                                                                                                                          |
```

**Analysis of the second query**

```
-- This query doesn't have either a WHERE clause, so, indexes will be used 
-- based on ORDER BY + LIMIT (and, eventually, column coverage).
-- * The index helping this case is the one corresponding to 
--   ON api_meterdata (datetime), because that's the only column used in the
--   ORDER BY.
-- * A second index will help: the one used for the JOIN condition
-- * How does postgresql choose to JOIN will depend on specific data values 
--   distribution
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT 
    api_meterdata.id, api_meterdata.meter_id, api_meterdata.datetime, 
    api_meter.id 
FROM 
    api_meterdata 
    INNER JOIN api_meter ON ( api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id ) 
ORDER BY 
    api_meterdata.datetime ASC 
LIMIT 100;
```

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                       |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=0.57..20.71 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=0.041..0.201 rows=100 loops=1)                                                                          |
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..130514.61 rows=648001 width=20) (actual time=0.040..0.182 rows=100 loops=1)                                                       |
|         ->  Index Scan using api_meterdata_datetime_idx on api_meterdata  (cost=0.42..20342.44 rows=648001 width=16) (actual time=0.036..0.048 rows=100 loops=1) |
|         ->  Index Only Scan using api_meter_pkey on api_meter  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=100)                      |
|               Index Cond: (id = api_meterdata.meter_id)                                                                                                          |
|               Heap Fetches: 100                                                                                                                                  |
| Planning time: 0.113 ms                                                                                                                                          |
| Execution time: 0.224 ms                                                                                                                                         |
```

**Analysis of your 3rd query without and with the index suggested**

```
-- This query doesn't have either a WHERE clause.
-- Again indexes will be used based on ORDER BY + LIMIT 
-- * The index that would mostly he,p this case would be one with 
--   (datetime ASC, id DESC). 
--   But there's not in place. An index with (datetime) will not be good enough,
--   because the second condition in ORDER BY will need to be evaluated before
--   the LIMIT can be computed. That is a SORT will be needed 
-- * A second index will help: the one used for the JOIN condition
-- * How does postgresql choose to JOIN will depend on specific data values 
--   distribution, as always.
--
-- This query performs MUCH WORSE than the previous one.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT api_meterdata.id, api_meterdata.meter_id, api_meterdata.datetime, api_meter.id 
FROM api_meterdata 
    INNER JOIN api_meter ON ( api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id ) 
ORDER BY api_meterdata.datetime ASC, api_meterdata.id DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                             |
| :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=43662.02..43662.27 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=377.202..377.222 rows=100 loops=1)                                     |
|   ->  Sort  (cost=43662.02..45282.03 rows=648001 width=20) (actual time=377.202..377.210 rows=100 loops=1)                             |
|         Sort Key: api_meterdata.datetime, api_meterdata.id DESC                                                                        |
|         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB                                                                                      |
|         ->  Hash Join  (cost=2.87..18895.89 rows=648001 width=20) (actual time=0.034..270.809 rows=648001 loops=1)                     |
|               Hash Cond: (api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id)                                                                       |
|               ->  Seq Scan on api_meterdata  (cost=0.00..9983.01 rows=648001 width=16) (actual time=0.007..75.104 rows=648001 loops=1) |
|               ->  Hash  (cost=1.83..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=83 loops=1)                                   |
|                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11kB                                                                      |
|                     ->  Seq Scan on api_meter  (cost=0.00..1.83 rows=83 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.009 rows=83 loops=1)            |
| Planning time: 0.123 ms                                                                                                                |
| Execution time: 377.251 ms                                                                                                             |
```

index creation (and removal of a redundant one)

```
-- We DROP one of the indexes... which will become redundant
-- CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_datetime_idx ON api_meterdata (datetime) ;
DROP INDEX api_meterdata_datetime_idx ;

-- And create one with two columns, and ordered in the same fashion need by the query
CREATE INDEX api_meterdata_datetime_idx 
    ON api_meterdata (datetime ASC, id DESC) ;
```

Analysis of the query under the new scenario

```
--
-- We put in place the required index
--
-- This query is again fast, and has an execution plan equivalent in 
-- structure to the two first ones. No SORT phase is needed, because rows are
-- already retrieved in the correct order, and once the LIMIT is reached, no
-- more rows are read from (disk/cache)
--

EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT 
    api_meterdata.id, api_meterdata.meter_id, api_meterdata.datetime, 
    api_meter.id 
FROM 
    api_meterdata 
    INNER JOIN api_meter ON ( api_meterdata.meter_id = api_meter.id ) 
ORDER BY 
    api_meterdata.datetime ASC, api_meterdata.id DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

```
| QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                       |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Limit  (cost=0.57..21.86 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=0.019..0.229 rows=100 loops=1)                                                                          |
|   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..137986.99 rows=648001 width=20) (actual time=0.018..0.214 rows=100 loops=1)                                                       |
|         ->  Index Scan using api_meterdata_datetime_idx on api_meterdata  (cost=0.42..27814.81 rows=648001 width=16) (actual time=0.013..0.040 rows=100 loops=1) |
|         ->  Index Only Scan using api_meter_pkey on api_meter  (cost=0.14..0.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=100)                      |
|               Index Cond: (id = api_meterdata.meter_id)                                                                                                          |
|               Heap Fetches: 100                                                                                                                                  |
| Planning time: 0.218 ms                                                                                                                                          |
| Execution time: 0.262 ms                                                                                                                                         |
```